# Clojure Noir routing priority

Tags: clojure, routes, noir

I am working on a web application with Noir. However, I am experiencing problem with routing. Here's the code sample from my controller:

```
(defpage [:get "/users/add"] []
    (common/layout
      [:div.row
       [:div.span12
        [:div.page-header
         [:h2 "Add User"]]
        (form-to {:class "form-horizontal"} [:post "/users/add"]
         (user-form {:id ""
                    :first_name ""
                    :last_name ""
                    :login ""
                    :email ""
                    :admin false
                    :staff false
                    :manager false
                    :customer false})
         [:div.control-group
          [:div.controls
           (submit-button {:class "btn btn-primary"} "Edit")]])]]))


(defpage [:get "/users/:id" :id #"\d+"] {:keys [id]}
(let [user (user/get-by-id id)]
    (common/layout
      [:div.row
       [:div.span12
        [:div.page-header
         [:h2 "View User"]]
        [:h3 (str (user :first_name) " " (user :last_name))]
        [:dl.dl-horizontal
         [:dt "login"]
         [:dd (user :login)]
         [:dt "e-mail"]
         [:dd (user :email)]
         [:dt "admin"]
         [:dd (if (user :admin) [:i.icon-ok ""] [:i.icon-remove ""])]
         [:dt "staff"]
         [:dd (if (user :staff) [:i.icon-ok ""] [:i.icon-remove ""])]
         [:dt "manager"]
         [:dd (if (user :manager) [:i.icon-ok ""] [:i.icon-remove ""])]
         [:dt "customer"]
         [:dd (if (user :customer) [:i.icon-ok ""] [:i.icon-remove ""])]]
        [:div.form-actions
         [:a.btn.btn-primary {:href (str "/users/" (user :id) "/edit")} "Edit"] " "
         [:a.btn.btn-danger {:href (str "/users/" (user :id) "/remove")} "Remove"] " "
         [:a.btn {:href "/users"} "All users"]]]])))
```

Every time I am requesting "/users/add", the request is being routed to "/user/:id" (it is fine when I remove /user/add action). I have very similar code for another controller and it is working fine. What might be the problem? How to set routing priorities?

Thanks,
Jacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a little difference in your code in comparison with routes tutorial on webnoir.org.

Yours:

```
(defpage [:get "/users/:id" :id #"\d+"] {:keys [id]}
```

On [webnoir](http://www.webnoir.org/tutorials/routes):

```
(defpage [:get ["/user/:id" :id #"\d+"]] {:keys [id]}
               ^                      ^
```

But maybe it doesn't make a difference in the end...

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/ibdknox/noir/blob/master/src/noir/core.clj#L80) noir puts every route into a map, hence there is no way to guarantee ordering of the dispatches.

In noir.core:

```
(defonce noir-routes (atom {}))
...
(swap! noir-routes assoc ~(keyword fn-name) 
     (~action ~url {params# :params} (~fn-name params#)))
```

Later in noir.server.handler:

```
(defn add-route-middleware [rts]
  (let [ws (all-wrappers)]
                         ;Iterates over entries in a map, no particular order
    (for [[route-name route] rts] 
      (try-wrap (ws route-name) route))))

(defn- pack-routes []
  (apply routes (concat (add-route-middleware @noir/pre-routes)
                        (add-route-middleware @noir/noir-routes)
                        (add-route-middleware @noir/post-routes)
                        @noir/compojure-routes)))
```

I guess if you have [less then 16 routes](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d0c380d9809fd242bec688c7134e900f0bbedcac/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java#L32) noir uses PersistentArrayMap and ordering is preserved, but as soon as you cross this boundary routing is broken. My only advice is to use unambiguous URLs.

**EDIT:** Here's a [bug report](https://github.com/noir-clojure/noir/issues/123) on a similar issue.

Comment: As an extension, you can feed it Compojure routing setups, which while they aren't quite as independent as Noir's routes, maintain their ordering.

Comment: Davidbe's answer made it work, however I believe there might be a problem with Noir. Routes in my other controllers do not have regexp specified but are working as expected.

Comment: @Jacek Well looking at the current implementation I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @IvanKoblik Please be more specific.

Comment: @Jacek Sure, as soon as number of handlers becomes greater then 16, order in which you specify handlers will not matter anymore. This is because Clojure when creating `{}` by default uses `PersistentArrayMap` which keeps entries in the same order as they were added, it automatically switches to `PersistentHashMap` when number of entries is more then 16, which will reorder the entries. It matters because handlers are kept in a map. -> If you have 2 handlers that overlap there is a chance that the one that were specified second will be checked first.